# Having trouble understanding reading text files in C#

Tags: c#, file-handling

So i'm in my 1st year of college, C# in Visual Studio is one of six modules.

Basically my problem is, i need to read in a value that's in a .txt file and calculate commission from that value.

The .txt file consists of:

```
1,Pat Ryan,280
2,Mary Smith,300
3,Tom Lynch,20
```

The 3rd value on each line is what i need to calculate the commission but i can't wrap my head around getting that value since you can't just pick out a value with the code we are currently using, you need to go through each line to get to the next.

[This is](http://pastebin.com/W8NY6Mdv) what i've done so far. I tried doing the calculations this way:

```
if (columns [0] < 1000) {commission = column[0] * .05}
```

But get an error:

> "Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string[]' and 'int'"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
static void salesReport() 
{
    string path =  "sales.txt";
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    StreamReader salesReport = new StreamReader(fs);

    string inputText = salesReport.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}{1,-30}{2,-20}\n", "Number","Name","Sales");

    while (inputText != null)
    {
        string[] columns = new string [3];

        columns = inputText.Split(',');

        Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}{1,-30}{2,-10}\n", columns[0], columns[1], columns[2]);

        inputText = salesReport.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here instead of an external website so we can still see everything if the link goes dead.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question to include the code (instead of a pastebin link).

Comment: You got pretty close. Just google your error and you'll find the solution. Google: `Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string[]' and 'int'`

Comment: Oh man, are you allowed to use the `Split` function?

Comment: You should use a using block around your StreamReader.  If an exception is thrown, your stream will not be closed properly.

Comment: nobody has mentioned File.ReadAllText() ???  well at least split was mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot perform a comparison operation between a string and int as specified in your error. You will need to cast the value you get from the text file to int and then do a comparison.

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(columns[2]) < 1000) 
{
    commission = Convert.ToInt32(columns[2]) / .05;
}
```

Looks like you want the 3rd column, I have changed the index to 2.

Answer (score 2):

here is a quick example of trying to parse a file and do what you want.  This has a lot of bad practices, such has the way I am concatenating the output string, but you should get the idea.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Path\To\File.txt"))
    {
        string line;

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] stuff = line.Split(',');

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(stuff[0]);
            string name = stuff[1];
            int val = Convert.ToInt32(stuff[2]);

            double commission = (double)val * 0.05;

            Console.WriteLine(name + "'s Commission: " + commission.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Plus, I hope you realize that you want to use * to compute commission vs /.  Image you sold a $200 item.  If you divide, then with 0.05 %, you would get $4000 commission.  You should be multiplying.

Comment: My mistake i threw that calculation in quickly without thinking because i took it out earlier!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (int.Parse(columns[0]) < 1000) {commission = int.Parse(columns[0]) * .05}​
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are not evaluating an integer. You are attempting to apply your comparison operator to the string representation after the `split` operation.

I added a method `safeToInt` which will prevent pesky exceptions if the string is not an int. Of course, if you want to be aware of those errors, you should just use `Int32.TryParse` directly and evaluate the boolean result.

I did not change your code to use the method I added for you :-) You should be able to figure that out.

```
static void salesReport() {
    string path =  "sales.txt";
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader salesReport = new StreamReader(fs);
    string inputText = salesReport.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}{1,-30}{2,-20}\n", "Number","Name","Sales");
    while (inputText != null) {
        string[] columns = new string [3];
        columns = inputText.Split(',');
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-15}{1,-30}{2,-10}\n", columns[0], columns[1], columns[2]);
        inputText = salesReport.ReadLine();
    }
}

static int safeToInt(string input, int defaultValue = 0){
    int result = 0;
    if(Int32.TryParse(input, out result)){
        return result;
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
```